# FlexNativeMenu with robotlegs

Tags: air, robotlegs

I an using the Robotlegs framework and I am busy with an AIR desktop application and I want to use FlexNativeMenu.  THe problem is that I am not able to create a view class based on mx.controls.FlexNativeMenu for dependency injection.  When not using Robotlegs the code is pretty straightforward - any help will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to mediate the menu?

Answer (score 1):

generally you can use whatever you want to a view. The problem is that the mediator's onRegister method will be called only if your view dispatches ADDED_TO_STAGE event. And because FlexNativeMenu doesn't fire this event your mediator is not working (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/FlexNativeMenu.html#eventSummary)

Answer (score 0):

### for RobotLegs v2

If you're trying to inject **into** the FlexNativeMenu (hereinafter referred to FNM), you can try something like this *(I'd do this in your IConfig implementor)*:

```
injector.injectInto( fnmInstance );
```

If you are trying to inject an instance of FNM *(say in it's mediator)*:

```
[Inject]
public var view:MyFNMClass;
```

If you are trying to attach a mediator to the FNM instance you do something like this in your IConfig implementor:

```
//requires that you map the FNM (assuming you're subclassing it)
mediatorMap.map( MyFNMClass ).toMediator( MyFNMClassMediator );

//else where where you decide to wire it up
mediatorMap.mediate( fnmInstance );
```

The **"gotcha"** is this: There isn't a very pretty way to access the FNM prior to injection.  I grabbed it like so:

```
//very nasty I know
var fnm:MyFlexNativeMenu = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.myMenu;
```

---

### code

Made a git repo - https://github.com/jusopi/RobotLegs-v2-FlexNativeMenu-example